# Why is the same request in nextjs, but the preflight is 200 and the post request is cors error?

Tags: rest, next.js, cors

### Symptom

[image]

I configured front page with nextj and configured to communicate with external example.com through rest api. There is no proxy server or other service in front.

[image]

In my nextjs, I send two requests, but if the type is preflight, it works normally with a 200 status. Other requests returned cors errors.

When I checked the normal response header of the server address, which is the request url, it was as follows.

```
access-control-allow-headers: Content-Type
access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
access-control-allow-origin: *
```

### Tried way

Thinking that everything is allowed on the server side, I searched the Internet and tried the following settings in my nextjs.

server.js

```
const corsRewrites = async() => {
   return [
     {
       source: '/:path*',
       destination: 'https://example.com/:path*',
     },
   ];
};
```

next.config.js

```
async headers() {
     return [
     {
       source: "/(.*)",
       headers: [
      { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", value: "false" },
      { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", value: "*" },
      { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", value: "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT" },
      { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", value: "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X- Api-Version" }
     ]
     }
     ]
},
```

I did the above, built it successfully and ran it, but it still returned the cors error. The same symptom occurred on localhost.

In the current situation, it is not possible to change the settings of the server providing the service.

I give a normal response in preflight and generate a cors error in other requests, and I don't know how to solve this in the client. The server that provides the service communicates normally with other servers and "access-control-allow-origin: *" is set, but I don't understand why cors errors occur.
Any help on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Edit your question to show the relevant client code. You may be including a header to your request that's disallowed by the CORS config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.

The server making the request must make a request with a specific id value. Otherwise, a cors error occurs because the access origin address is not properly handed over.

If the value of Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the server is '*', you must check the authentication method or code value. The cors error is most likely not a server-side problem.